# How to apply more than one filter in angularJs

Tags: html, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i'm applying two filters on a div like

```
 <div  ng-repeat="item1 in filterItems(d) |  filter:query | findobj : selected ">
```

But its not working properly

Here is the  [Working Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1joo0j77/6/)

Comment: What's the role of `findobj`?

Comment: @ Alberto I.N.J.  It will display only selected option

Comment: Both filters appear to work correctly in the Jsfiddle you posted; however, they are *both* applied (which is normal), if you pick one of the dropdown options, the text box can only further filter from that category, yet you only appear to have one item per category.

Comment: Just like `filter:query`?

Comment: if you want one filter to reset the other, that's a different question entirely.  I would recommend you update your question to provide a bit more detail than just "it's not working properly"

Comment: @Claies but if type Goto or Preamble or something full word then its not working

Comment: ok well that makes sense as well, since the filter applies to the Values, not the Keys....

Comment: Goto, for example, isn't even part of your data to be filtered, it is static HTML content in the repeater.

Comment: @Claies i wanted to implement the filter for an entire html page or on the content inside that div

Comment: you seem to misunderstand how a filter works.  You can't filter arbitrary HTML.  The filter is applied to your Data *before* the HTML is rendered by Angular.

Comment: there isn't an angular filter that would provide that implementation.

Comment: @Claies it should display every matching words from that div tag

Comment: not possible using angular; you might be able to find some JQuery logic and wrap it in a Directive, though....

Comment: @Flash Why not use 2 filters? **E.g.** `<div ng-repeat="item1 in filterItems(d) | filter: query | filter: selected">`

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. that is what he's using, but he wants the filter to apply to the rendered HTML, not  `item1`....

Comment: @Claies If all your text are rendered from a JS object, you can do it through angularJS. Maybe the best advice would be to store all the content into objects. Then you can build a filter "selectWords" or whatever  that return just the matching words.

Comment: @Okazari yes, but if you look at the template he is trying to "filter", it is full of expressions that are evaluated based on the data in the `ng-repeat`.  There wouldn't be any direct conversion from that HTML to a string representation that I can see.....

Comment: @Okazari so is there any way to solve it using angular

Comment: @Claies Yup, will have to fallback to a custom directive.  atFlash -  But since it is a fixed list. Why don't you use a combobox ? It's a bit nonsense to allow this type of filter on a defined list. If you want to allow the user to filter on the words from your "items" you can use it.

Comment: @Okazari can please update inside a Jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

The best i can do is this.

It's not the sexiest, but it works.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwcydgtv/2/)

HTML :

Added a select

```
<select ng-model="category2">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Goto">Goto</option>
    <option value="MainHeading">MainHeading</option>
    <option value="PageID">PageID</option>
</select>
```

Added this kind of clauses to your html div

```
ng-show="category2=='Goto'||category2===''"
```

JS : Just intialized the var to ''

```
$scope.category2 = "";
```

That's not exactly what you're looking for. That's not the best things to do. But at least it works.

Hope it helped